# Rename Length to Diameter in WooCommerce formatted product dimensions output

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, dimensions

I’m using this **`woocommerce_format_dimensions`** filter hook to replace displayed dimensions format from **1 x 1 x 1 in** to **1 L in. x 1 W in. x 1 H in.**

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_format_dimensions', 'custom_formated_product_dimentions', 10, 2 );
function custom_formated_product_dimentions( $dimension_string, $dimensions ){
    if ( empty( $dimension_string ) )
        return __( 'N/A', 'woocommerce' );

    $dimensions = array_filter( array_map( 'wc_format_localized_decimal', $dimensions ) );
    foreach( $dimensions as $key => $dimention )
        $label_with_dimensions[$key] = $dimention . ' ' . strtoupper( substr($key, 0, 1) ) . ' ' . get_option( 'woocommerce_dimension_unit' ) . '.';

    return implode( ' x ',  $label_with_dimensions);
}
```

**`var_dump`** of **$dimensions** array looks like this:

```
array(3) { ["length"]=> string(3) "104" ["width"]=> string(3) "136" ["height"]=> string(2) "53" }
```

How could I rename **“length”** key to **“diameter”** and change the order of dimensions to be in reverse, so that final result would be:

**1 H in. x 1 W in. x 1 D in.**

I have tried to rename keys in **$dimensions** array using **`array_map`**, but couldn't manage to get it working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update 2020**

You just need to set the **`array`** **`keys`**/**`values`** as you want them in your function (renaming one key and reordering your array), this way:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_format_dimensions', 'Custom_formated_product_dimentions_with_labels', 10, 2 );
function Custom_formated_product_dimentions_with_labels( $dimension_string, $dimensions ){
    if ( empty( $dimension_string ) )
        return __( 'N/A', 'woocommerce' );

    // Set here your new array of dimensions based on existing keys/values
    $new_dimentions = array(
        'height' => $dimensions['height'],
        'width'  => $dimensions['width'],
        'diameter' => $dimensions['length']
    );

    $dimensions = array_filter( array_map( 'wc_format_localized_decimal', $new_dimentions ) );

    $label_with_dimensions = array();

    foreach( $dimensions as $key => $dimention ){
        $dimensions[$key] = ucfirst($key) . ' ' . $dimention . ' ' . get_option( 'woocommerce_dimension_unit' );
    }

    return implode( ' x ',  $dimensions) . '.';
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

This code is tested on WooCommerce versions 3+ and works