# Display the width before the height in Woocommerce confirmation email

Tags: email, woocommerce

In the woocommerce confirmation email the dimension height come before the width. I need to invert it and have the width before height. I think the output of the information is coming from this action:

```
    // allow other plugins to add additional product information here.
    do_action( 'woocommerce_order_item_meta_start', $item_id, $item, $order, $plain_text );
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Your question is not clear as by default there is no displayed width and height in the email notifications… So you have maid some customizations and ou should give details and code about them, as nobody can guess that.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to mention that i used the woocommerce measuerment price calculator plugin. This plugin adds height and with to the email confimation. You can not change the default order but you can change the labels of width and height to height and width. This is a pretty easy workaround.

Comment: You could try something like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48504782/reorder-and-customize-product-dimensions-formatted-output-in-woocommerce/48505269#48505269 … But not sure that this plugin uses `wc_format_dimensions()` function for displaying dimensions.