# Customizing product dimensions output on front end + change dimensions title

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, dimensions

Using *"[Reorder and customize product dimensions formatted output in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48504782/reorder-and-customize-product-dimensions-formatted-output-in-woocommerce/48505269#48505269)"* answer code il would like to make the output display as:

Size: D40 x W45 x H60 (cm)

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: No, just putting “Problem” in front of your description of what you _want_, does still not make this a proper problem description. Again: What _happens_ with the code you have tried?

Comment: @misorude, have updated the question. made it more simple. Hope this helps

Comment: @misorude,Well it does say if you use the code you get this Dimensions: L 40 x W 45 x H 60 cm

 but I want this Size: D40 x W45 x H60 (cm)

Sorry I don't know how to write this any clearer.

Comment: Why not use str_replace ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow!
Try a simpler code (tested):

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_format_dimensions', 'custom_formated_product_dimentions', 10, 2 );
function custom_formated_product_dimentions( $dimension_string, $dimensions ){
    if ( empty( $dimension_string ) )
        return __( 'N/A', 'woocommerce' );

    $dimensions = array_filter( array_map( 'wc_format_localized_decimal', $dimensions ) );

    return 'D'.$dimensions['length'].' x W'.$dimensions['width'].' x H'.$dimensions['height'].' ('.get_option( 'woocommerce_dimension_unit' ).')';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add the follows code snippet in your active theme's functions.php to achieve the above -

```
function woocommerce_display_product_attributes( $product_attributes, $product ){
    if( !isset( $product_attributes['dimensions'] ) ) return $product_attributes;

    $modified_dimensions = array();
    foreach ( $product->get_dimensions( false ) as $key => $value ) {
        if( $key == 'length' )
            $modified_dimensions[$key] = 'D'.$value;
        if( $key == 'width' )
            $modified_dimensions[$key] = 'W'.$value;
        if( $key == 'height' )
            $modified_dimensions[$key] = 'H'.$value;
    }
    $dimension_string = implode( ' &times; ', array_filter( array_map( 'wc_format_localized_decimal', $modified_dimensions ) ) );

    if ( ! empty( $dimension_string ) ) {
        $dimension_string .= ' (' . get_option( 'woocommerce_dimension_unit' ) . ')';
    } else {
        $dimension_string = __( 'N/A', 'woocommerce' );
    }
    // change dimensions label & value.
    $product_attributes['dimensions']['label']  = __( 'Size', 'text-domain' );
    $product_attributes['dimensions']['value']  = $dimension_string;
    return $product_attributes;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_display_product_attributes', 'woocommerce_display_product_attributes', 99, 2 );
```

Comment: thank you but its not working for me. I have since realized that I also have some more code in functions.php to allow Dimensions to be displayed in product page, and archive pages. I now see in this code I can change the Dimensions title. Maybe this code conflicts with yours. I will update the original code above if I can.

Comment: This is a tested code. Just make sure to remove all your previous related codes. Or maybe your theme have done some hard customisation on it. Just be sure.