# Display and save formated dimensions of the product everywhere

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, dimension

Inspired by  [Display the weight of cart and order items in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51851028/display-the-weight-of-cart-and-order-items-in-woocommerce) @LoicTheAztec's answer, making some changes by replacing product weight by product dimensions, I am able to show the items dimensions everywhere on cart items and order items.

The problem is that I don't know how to show the labels or adjectives:

Longitud cm x Ancho cm x Alto cm for a Spanish site.

I really appreciate any help.

```
// Display the cart item dimensions in cart and checkout pages 
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_item_data', 'display_custom_item_data_dimensions', 10, 2 ); 
function display_custom_item_data_dimensions( $cart_item_data, $cart_item ) { 
    if ( $cart_item['data']->has_dimensions() > 0 ){ 
        $cart_item_data[] = array( 'name' => __( 'Dimensions', 'woocommerce' ), 'value' => $cart_item['data']->get_dimensions() . ' ' . get_option('woocommerce_dimensions_unit') ); 
    } 
    return $cart_item_data; 
}

// Save and Display the order item dimensions (everywhere) 
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item', 'display_order_item_data_dimensions', 20, 4 ); 
function display_order_item_data_dimensions( $item, $cart_item_key, $values, $order ) { 
    if ( $values['data']->has_dimensions() > 0 ){ 
        $item->update_meta_data( __( 'Dimensions', 'woocommerce' ), $values['data']->get_dimensions() . ' ' . get_option('woocommerce_dimensions_unit') ); 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First the method `get_dimensions()` has an option to display formatted dimensions, so you can change dimension formatting using the following, to add dimension labels as desired:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_format_dimensions', 'custom_formated_product_dimentions', 10, 2 );
function custom_formated_product_dimentions( $dimension_string, $dimensions ){
    $text_domain    = 'woocommerce';
    $dimension_unit = get_option('woocommerce_dimensions_unit');

    if ( empty( $dimension_string ) )
        return __( 'N/A', $text_domain );

    // Set here your new array of dimensions based on existing keys/values
    $new_dimensions = array(
        __('width', $text_domain)  => $dimensions['width'],
        __('length', $text_domain) => $dimensions['length'],
        __('height', $text_domain) => $dimensions['height'],
    );

    $dimensions = array_filter( array_map( 'wc_format_localized_decimal', $new_dimensions ) );

    // Loop through new dimensions array adding spanish labels 
    foreach( $dimensions as $key => $dimention ){
        $dimensions[$key] = ucfirst($key) . ' ' . $dimention. ' ' . $dimension_unit;
    }

    return implode( ' &times; ',  $dimensions);
}
```

For Spanish language, you can translate strings with [Loco plugin](https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/loco-translate/) or you can replace:

```
$new_dimensions = array(
    __('width', $text_domain)  => $dimensions['width'],
    __('length', $text_domain) => $dimensions['length'],
    __('height', $text_domain) => $dimensions['height'],
);
```

by:

```
$new_dimensions = array(
    __('longitud', $text_domain) => $dimensions['width'],
    __('ancho', $text_domain)    => $dimensions['length'],
    __('alto', $text_domain)     => $dimensions['height'],
);
```

Now on your code you will use `get_dimensions( true )` method to display formatted dimensions as follow:

```
// Display the cart item dimensions in cart and checkout pages
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_item_data', 'display_custom_item_data_dimensions', 10, 2 );
function display_custom_item_data_dimensions( $cart_item_data, $cart_item ) {
    $product =  $cart_item['data'];

    if ( $product->has_dimensions() ){
        $cart_item_data[] = array(
            'name' => __( 'Dimensions', 'woocommerce' ),
            'value' => $product->get_dimensions( true ),
        );
    }
    return $cart_item_data;
}

// Save and Display the order item dimensions (everywhere)
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item', 'display_order_item_data_dimensions', 10, 4 );
function display_order_item_data_dimensions( $item, $cart_item_key, $values, $order ) {
    $product =  $values['data'];

    if ( $product->has_dimensions() ){
        $item->update_meta_data( __( 'Dimensions', 'woocommerce' ), $product->get_dimensions( true ) );
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

> **Note:** As `has_dimensions()` is a conditional method returning a boolean value, it doesns't need anything else as a condition.

Similar: [Rename Length to Diameter in WooCommerce formatted product dimensions output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45401876/rename-length-to-diameter-in-woocommerce-formatted-product-dimensions-output/45402139#45402139)

[image]

Comment: Thanks @LoicTheAztec there is a point and compare error in the second code.

Comment: Does not show (cm) in each unit. longitud is 
length, ancho is width `        __('longitud', $text_domain)    => $dimensions['length'],
        __('ancho', $text_domain) => $dimensions['width'],
        __('alto', $text_domain)     => $dimensions['height'],`

Comment: Something strange happens, when I use your full code it doesn't show me (cm). But if you combine your code with the one I'm modifying, it works perfectly. Similarly, thank you very much.

Comment: @Williams On last woocommerce version with Storefront theme it works nicely... So maybe something else is interacting.

Comment: Yeah i thought i probably have something to do with my theme i think i have outdated woocommerce files. But everything is perfect, thank you very much from Venezuela, you are a genius.