# display custom fields data using meta key in woocommerce official android app

Tags: php, android, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

inspired by the question [Woocommerce mobile app display custom field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62251768/woocommerce-mobile-app-display-custom-field) which did not have any response, I have also investigated about this issue but I do not get any answer or solution. My intention is also to show in the woocommerce android application the data of the custom fields that I have in the billing and shipping forms. I use different php codes to display custom field data in php templates, such as: `

```
<?php
    $custom_order_meta = get_post_meta($order->get_order_number(), 'order_field_custom_key_meta', true);

    if( ! empty($custom_order_meta) )
    { ?>
<p> <?php
printf( '<strong>Title Field:</strong> ' . esc_html( '%s', 'woocommerce' ), esc_html($custom_order_meta)  );?> 
</p> <?php 
    }
    ?>
```

`
I use this code to display custom field data in order emails in the billing and shipping address section.

I attach an image of the official woocommerce application so that it is better understood. In the image you can see that by default the application only shows the preview of the basic data of the billing and shipping address.

[image: Woocommerce Oficial App Android]

For the products I use the code of [Display and save formated dimensions of the product everywhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63255270/display-and-save-formated-dimensions-of-the-product-everywhere) which shows the weight and dimensions of the product in all parts of the website, but it may appear that these are not shown in the woocommerce android application either.

[image: Capture of the official woocommerce android application that does not show the weight and dimensions.]

I appreciate any help will be welcome, thank you.

Comment: any answer of your question sir ?

Comment: @Hannah James no, I have not received an answer to my question yet.

Comment: anyone got answer for this question?